# How to add "time" data this?

Tags: loop, post-meta, views

I am using this simple snippets to get [post view count](http://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/) for a long time 
I was wondering if we can add a "time" data ?
Because I would like to show the view of yesterday/ 2 days ago / 2 days ago etc... ?

we can display in sidebar like MOST POPULAR POSTS OF THE **DAY**, **MONTH** or **HOURS** (if possible)

here is my sidebar code

```
 <?php query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&posts_per_page=4&order=DESC');    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>            
<a class="tab_caption" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $post_title; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?></a>  

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Well a nice. I suggest everyone to search the question before asking it. I was about to ask the same question. Many thanks looking forward for helpful replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the code you are using to count views does store the count data as a `custom_field` value. If I want the functionality you mentioned in question, I'd rather use a custom plugin to create a separate table in database to store view count and respective dates. So doing some queries you can display popular posts by date/month etc.

Comment: thats ok amit this snipett author kevin say 

"wp_get_archives lets you define a short time period something like this I think would be useful. "

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

i m bit confused